# Get list of primary keys deleted in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a Parent table A with following attributes(columns) { PKA, a1, a2...} and child table B with following attributes {FKA, b1, b2...} 
PKA is the primary key (auto increment) for table A and table B does not have any primary keys but it has a Foreign key column FKA that references PKA column of table A ( 1: n relationship)

Adding entries:
when I add an entry into table A ...I use the PDO API lastInsertId()  to get the record inserted and use this value to populate FKA in table B.

Problem:
1. While deleting entries however, I did not find an API 'lastDeleteId()' that I could use in a similar way

Even Bigger Problem:
 when my delete happens on table A, by design, the delete command is: DELETE from table A where a1 = . This a1 column is non- unique so the DELETE command can return multiple PKA keys that need to be flushed from table B

Things to note:

1. I am using PDO API
2. MySQL tables (under consideration here) are InnoDB
3. I'm running in Transaction mode ( multiple SQL calls between beginTransaction() and commit()/rollback()
4. Not looking for CASCADE ON DELETE option

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Every table should havea PK, how can you uniquely id a record? This is esepcially important in deleting.

Comment: @HLGEM a counter-example to your affirmation is the fact that Many-To-Many link tables do not need nor should they use PK unless you're using both FK as a multi-column PK.

Comment: @HLGEM This is not necessarily true. Other columns can be used to delete records. I specifically do not require to uniquely identify a record in table B..in my case adding a PK to table B is redundant

Comment: Are you specifically avoiding the data-integrity solution (`ON DELETE CASCADE`) because you need to handle some application level logic (deleting files specified in the child table as a filename)?

Comment: @PK is never redundant, If you have a natural key, that should be designated as the PK.

Comment: If so, my second solution should work well for you even if you have data-integrity constraints in place. You select the data first - work on application level logic - emit one `DELETE` statement and allow the system to `CASCADE` instead of emitting 2 `DELETE`s. But it does have downsides.

Comment: @HLGEM I did not suggest that PKs are unnecessary, I was suggesting that uniquely identifying a row is not always defined via one single column (in the case of Many-To-Many tables I suggested multi-column PKs); what I suggesting is that not every table needs a single-column PK. I find your reply offensive and would like to end this here now (by discontinuing further debate) before this escalates.

Comment: A PK does not have to be one column, but it is ireesponsible to not define one.

Comment: @HLGEM No need for name calling to make your point.

Comment: @MihaiStancu yes I am avoiding the ON DELETE CASCADE solution for similar reasons. I will try to incorporate your second solution and revert back. Thanks for your answers and comments

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs..it aided me in solving this problem: before deleting records in the parent table,  I fetched all the primary keys related that were required to be deleted i.e. SELECT PKA from table A where a1 = some value. Then I deleted all child entries from this array of PKAs followed by delete parent table. All these statements were part of transaction in case rollback was required. However, IMHO, it would be of great help for PDO to support an API like lastDeletedId() (returning an array of all deleted primary keys in the last sql call) on the lines of lastInsertedId().

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query right after your delete query or as a batch cleanup approach which will work retroactively for any child that wasn't deleted in tandem with the dependent parent:

```
DELETE
    FROM  table_a
    WHERE a1 = ?;
SELECT    id
    FROM  table_b
    WHERE FKA NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table_a);
```

Or you could run it right before the delete query using the same WHERE clause:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT    id
        FROM  table_b
        WHERE FKA NOT IN(
            SELECT id
                FROM table_a
                WHERE a1 = ?;
        );
    DELETE
        FROM  table_a
        WHERE a1 = ?;
COMMIT;
```

The second approach would need to be wrapped in a transaction to make sure you're deleting only the ids that were matched at the time of the select even if some other thread might have entered new data matching those filters.

### Edit - a matter of approach

If you're using `$pdo->beginTransaction()` and then you issue one `SELECT` statement, fetch the ids, work with them in the application level, then issue the `delete` statement, this will keep the transaction active and some records may be locked within that transactions especially if you use `FOR UPDATE` in the initial `select` statement and/or if you have high `ISOLATION LEVEL`s.

If you're using time-consuming operations in the application layer this will keep active locks in the DB for a long time and lower your application capacity for concurrent connections.

I'm an adept of avoiding multiple communication sessions with the DB server where one would suffice. That's why i wouldn't use `$pdo->beginTransaction()` in the first place.

I would extend my "fetch the ids to be deleted" query into a "fetch all data required in processing deleted records". I'd send the query to the server in one communication session within a transaction and the result set(s) of the `SELECT` satement(s) will be sent back to the application even if the data was deleted from storage by the time the application receives the payload.

Comment: Thanks! I think this might work ..but I believe this might be a bit too expensive considering large number of records. I will choose your answer if I do not get a better one!

Comment: If you have an FK, you never delete from the parent first unless you are using cascade delte. The purpose of the FK is to prevent you from deleting a parent record when there are child records.

Comment: @HLGEM that is if you are using `ON DELETE RESTRICT`, but on the other hand you **can** use `ON DELETE CASCADE` which deletes the child rows as well or `ON DELETE SET NULL` which just disconnects the child from the (now deleted) parent.

Comment: @MihaiStancu +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

What you do is select the records ids of the records you want to delete and place them in a temp table. Then you delete first from the child table, then the parent. Do this in transaction so if it errors the data is rolled back.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Instead of using temp table I did a pdo fetch() into array and iterated over this array to delete children first followed by parent

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way might be to copy the contents of table A into a temporary table, then perform the delete, then do a LEFT OUTER JOIN of your temporary table to the updated table and use that to find the rows that no longer have a counterpart.

Also, if you don't explicitly make a primary key, doesn't InnoDB make one under the hood for you? I thought the InnoDB storage engine requires one.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is not about primary key. As a part of transaction I receive following command: DELETE from table A where a1 = some value 1. This will delete a bunch of records in table A. I require to fetch the PKA value for these records. Then, I require to append DELETE from table B where FKA = PKA values fetched. So the question is how to get those PKA values for deleted records...I am sorry if I garbled up my question

Comment: I told you, you select them first and put them in a temp table and then dlete with joins to the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

How about just work on the idea that your data might not be consistent. That is, there might be a reference to a pk that has already been deleted. And just check it every time the fk is used.

Then add a scheduled task to clean up the records by checking using a select from where fk is not in (select pk).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to accomplish this as a part of transaction. The scheduled task would be an overhead given my application